# Save each line as a separate file

Tags: unix, vim

I would like to save each line of my file as separate file, using column 1 as the name of the file

```
AT1G01010       chr1    3631    5899
AT1G01020       chr1    6790    8737
AT1G01030       chr1    11649   13714
```

Desired output is a separate file for AT1G01010.txt whose contents are

```
AT1G01010       chr1    3631    5899
```

I know in vim this is possible using the command

```
:g/^/execute '.w '.line('.').'.txt'
```

But this generates a file that are named after the line number, which is not exactly the result I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this script:

```
while read line
do
    name=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
    echo "$line" > $name.txt
done < source_file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You're close. Instead of `line('.')`, you can use `expand('<cword>')` to extract the word under the cursor and include it in the filename. This uses the fact that `:global` places the cursor to the first character on each line.

```
:g/^/execute '.w '.expand('<cword>').'.txt'
```

For other words, you'd have to use a combination of `getline('.')` and `matchstr()` (or reposition the cursor first).

Answer (score 1):

In BASH it is as simple as this

```
cat test.txt | while read line
do  
    echo $line > $(cut -d " " -f1 <<< $line).txt
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
qq0"ayEV:w <C-R>a.txt<CR>q:%norm!@q
```

(where `<C-R>` is control key + r and `<CR>` is the enter key)

This should record and execute a macro that runs `:w FIRST_COLUMN.txt` for each line in the file.

Comment: I knew someone would come up with a macro solution!